# Setting one of 2 ImageViews transparent/invisible, shows white screen

Tags: android, imageview, visibility, transparent

I am a newbie and have been working on this for a couple of days now without any success. Somebody's help would be very appreciated.

I have two ImageViews, one behind the other in an Activity. I would like to make the first one (the one at the top), invisible or transparent, so I can use it internally in my code. The second one (the one on the bottom), should remain visible, so the user can interact with it. I tried doing it setting the canvas transparent first, and then the TOP ImageVIew, which causes the screen to show white color, instead of showing the ImageView behind (the BOTTOM one). Could somebody please, explain me why this is happening, and suggest me a better approach for achieving my purpose? Thanks in advance.

Here is my .java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView)imageView).getDrawable();
                    Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                    imgDrawable.draw(canvas);
                    int pixel = mutableBitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                    Log.i("PIXEL COLOR", ""+pixel);

                    int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
                    int red = Color.red(pixel);
                    int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
                    int green = Color.green(pixel);
                    String color = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X%02X", alpha, red, green, blue);
                    Log.i("RGB", color);

                    float[] hsv = new float[3];
                    Color.RGBToHSV(red, green, blue, hsv);
                    Log.i("HSV_H", "Hue=" + hsv[0]);
                    Log.i("HSV_H", "Saturation=" + hsv[1]);
                    Log.i("HSV_H", "Value=" + hsv[2]);
               }
               return true;
            }
        });
}
```

}

Here is my .xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lapices" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lapices" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what you are trying to achieve. 
And it should exist a better way, but as far as i can see if you turn your LinearLayout in RelativeLayout and you change the order of image views it should work.

By the way some code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply user2122876, very appreciated. I want to use 2 Imageview layers, one on the top of the other, and get user interaction from the top, invisible one, but I can not figure out how to do this in Android, since it seems that invisible ImageViews do not accept user interaction. Or is there a way of achieving this? Thanks again for your time.